# Request to reopen my Facebook question that I believe was wrongly marked as duplicate of a question closed as "needs details or clarity"

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, moderators, vote-to-close

In November 2011, I asked "[How do I let my Facebook friends view my Timeline posts without letting them comment on the posts?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/21231/7584)" I made sure to make my question clear, straightforward, and on-topic.

On Mar. 26, 2023, more than 11 years later, a mod unilaterally closed it as a duplicate of "[How to disable comments for my post in Facebook? (closed)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/26525/7584)", asked in May 2012, which was more than five months after my question. That question has been closed as “needs details or clarity”, forming a chain of closed questions, pointing my question to an apparently *low-quality question*, *and by extension, also marking my question as "needs details or clarity."* I am confused as to why my question, which has *remained open for more than 11 years*, suddenly “needed details or clarity.”

I believe that the usual good moderation practice in the SE network is to **not close questions as duplicates of low-quality questions (especially ones that are closed)**.

The duplicate target question is not helpful since it’s closed and doesn’t allow new answers to be posted. Facebook updates its site regularly, so a solution may come up for the problem I mentioned in the question. This issue I mentioned is still presently relevant and I still would like to know if there’s an answer to my question.

Since it is unclear what is unclear about my question, I request that it be reopened, or the dupe closure be reversed, since apparently, the other question is a bad question and "needs details or clarity". I believe my question is straightforward, clear, and on-topic: [How do I let my Facebook friends view my Timeline posts without letting them comment on the posts?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/21231/7584)

If it still needs details or clarity, then **how I can improve it to get it reopened? Which part of *my* question was unclear or lacking details?** What details do I need to add? I think the closure reason was vague and not explained well. I also think it would be fair if I had a chance to respond to attempts to close my question before a mod closed it unilaterally, as is good practice on most SE sites.

---

Update: I have edited the question to make it as clear as possible and added details, following the mod feedback on this meta post. However, it was [unilaterally left closed in the reopen review queue](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/155240) for the *second* time and remains closed as a duplicate of another closed question that "needs details or clarity," despite my edits to improve it. I don’t understand why this is the case and what else I can do to improve it. On other SE sites, I have seen that good moderation practice is to avoid closing questions as duplicates of closed questions. Could someone please explain this situation and provide some guidance?

Comment: The edits failed to improve the question. Post should not include meta commentary, should not include meta posts,even quotes from the [answer](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4956/88163)  to this question.

Comment: Maybe you will find helpful the [Journeyman's answer](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4974/88163) to another recent meta question about another recently closed question.

Comment: @Rubén Those are details I added to clarify my question and hopefully meet the reopening criteria. If there is anything else that I should include, please let me know. As for the other meta post, I kindly request you to review `@JourneymanGeek’s edit, as explained in [their answer](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4974/7584) in that meta post. I hope that it addresses your concerns and that you will consider reopening this question and the one mentioned in that meta post.

Comment: The mention of Journeymen's answer is to help  you to improve the question that is being requested to be reopened here. Please don't derail this or any other conversation.

Comment: @Rubén I have updated the post to remove the quotes. (I added them initially for context, to explain why I edited those details into the question.) I would appreciate it if you could tell me what else I need to do to get the question reopened. I respect your decision, and I also would like to know if I have exhausted my appeals to you and if you have made your final decision. If yes, I hope you don’t mind me bringing up my appeal to the Stack Exchange team.

Comment: "The duplicate target is not helpful since it’s closed and doesn’t allow new answers to be posted" . A post is not helpful/unhelpful because it's closed/open or allow/ doesn't allow new answers.

Comment: @Rubén What further details do I need to add to clarify my question and get it reopened?

Comment: Your question was already answered. See the duplicate target. You might have to make a feature request directly to Facebook.

Comment: @Rubén The duplicate target question (which has no solutions to the problem) is also closed. Facebook updates its site regularly, so an actual solution may come up for this problem eventually. However, if all the questions about it are closed, no one will be able to share that solution here. Is there anything else I could do to get my question reopened?  Please let me know if I have exhausted my appeals to you and if you have made your final decision. If yes, I hope you don’t mind me bringing up my appeal to the Stack Exchange team.

Comment: You have not presented solid arguments yet, apparently you haven't learned yet about about the features of Stack Exchange and that you wan't to use site in a way that is not intended. If you fix this question, the question on the main site I'm open to review them. I just will not do your job. Regarding fixing this question, this might help with some of it's problems [Common reasons why your meta post may be negatively received](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333476/289691)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145188/discussion-between-galacticninja-and-ruben).

Comment: Related: [Do the moderators plan to close most questions on this site?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4984/7584)

Comment: Relevant meta discussion started by a community manager about whether we should mandate research on questions: [Does Web Apps Stack Exchange Require Research?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5120/7584)

Answer (score -3):

## About the Duplicate Target

The question used as a target of close as duplicate, [How to disable comments for my post in Facebook?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/26525/88163), has

- a score of 15,
- 2 answers

  - each of them having a positive score above of 2.

Your question has

- a score of 3
- has 1 answer, having 0 score.

The date of the questions are irrelevant.

## "How can I improve my question to get it reopened?"

I don't give prescriptions. Below there are some ideas:

### Minimal

Briefly explain why the answers to the target duplicate didn't help you and why after so many years the question is still relevant for a large number of users.
Bear in mind that your question might be reviewed as if it was a new question: it should clearly describe a problem, what you have tried, show what you found from this site and from the Facebook help and why it didn't help you.

### Good

Once that you are taking the time to improve the question, really search throughly this site, not only looking for answer but also for related  posts that might be of interest for you and the readers of your question. Include relevant about the latest updates made to the app as well to the resources for end-users.

### Above

1. Explain what make you think that what you want to do is part of the built-in features of Facebook or that might be part added as an "add-on" or be part of a limited access set of features.
2. Show what you have tried
3. Tell us what kind of things do you think that might be good options as end-user for a very large number of end-users and what deters you from implementing that by yourself.

### Outstanding

Offer to collaborate with the community to find answers and/or work togheter around the topics of your question.

## Reference

### Web Applications Meta

- [What makes a post a duplicate of another, their content, their context or both?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3964/88163)

### Meta Stack Exchange

- [How does duplicate closing work? When is a question a duplicate, and how should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841/289691)

Comment: You forgot to mention that the target question is closed! How is it good to close questions as duplicates of questions that are also closed? Don't we want to encourage users to actually post answers to questions?

Comment: Questions should only be closed as duplicates if there is a *good* question with *good* answer(s) that answers the question. If it's a bad question, then don't point users to it.

Comment: @Flimm:  No.  If a bad question is asked and it is the duplicate of a closed bad question, the new question should still be closed as a duplicate.  Two bads don't make a good.  Of course I'm not saying that this is the case with this particular question, just making the general point.

Comment: @Chenmunka I couldn't disagree more strongly. The purpose of closing a question as a duplicate is to point everyone to a good question and a good answer. That's why you can't close a question as a duplicate of another question with no answers, for example. If the question is bad and there is no good duplicate question with a good answer, then close it as bad, not as a duplicate.