# This question is extremly clear and detailed, but closed. How can it be made clearer?

Tags: discussion

This question of mine was closed: [Can I add audio to recorder.google.com?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/169932/24544) ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZffBo.jpg))

It was closed for this reason:

> Closed. This question needs details or clarity. It is not currently accepting answers.

After it was closed, I edited it to add paragraphs of clarity and details. However, it still remains closed. A moderator commented:

> You might want to add the link to the "traditional" Help Center where this things belongs - support.google.com/pixelphone. The specfic help article (is the same from one of the screenshots): [Record audio on your Pixel phone](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/9516618?hl=en). Please remove the meta commentary.

This is confusing to me. What details or clarity does this question lack? The question is extremely clear and detailed, does it really need to be even more detailed? Why am I pointed to a help article that doesn't answer the question? The help article says how to upload audio using a Pixel phone. It doesn't say how to upload audio using a web browser. Maybe there is a way that isn't mentioned in the help documentation. Power users of web applications often find ways to do things that are undocumented. As a power user of recorder.google.com , I am interested in finding out if there is a way to upload audio using the web interface.

If the question should be closed for another reason, then why was it closed as lacking clarity or details?

Since apparently the meta commentary should be removed, I've asked the question here.

[Link to screenshot of comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JYJe.png)

Comment: As this question only includes [meta-tag:discussion] might not get the answer that you might be looking. Please use the appropiate meta tag, tags and tone. Ref. [What is "meta"? How does it work?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta).

Comment: Related: [Should we allow questions about (Google) Recorder?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4975/88163)

Comment: @Rubén I don't understand your comment about this question post, that it might not get an answer. I did include an appropriate meta tag. The link you posted does not suggest any tags besides "discussion", "feature-request", "bug", and "support", and I felt only "discussion" was relevant here.

Comment: A post having only [meta-tag:discussion] might only looking opinions from the community. The referred article explains the use of meta tags and suggest to [look around](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/search).  From this you could learn the tags used on similar questions.

Comment: Meanwhile when disclosing research in a concise manner, questions are still getting closed https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4992/18147 I have no clue how the moderator wants users to show research.

Comment: A relevant meta discussion post by a community manager who asked the community whether we should require research for questions: [Does Web Apps Stack Exchange Require Research?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5120/7584).

Answer (score 3):

Details isn't really about 'volume' - its about 'precision'. At the current moment, its just a chunk of irrelevant information that is confusing to a reader.

As a long time user of the network - when asking a question, I ask myself 'what does someone who is trying to answer the question need to know?"

Mentioning that there's no reference to this on the help and that the closest thing you could find was recording over the mobile UI is probably better than replicating a good chunk of the help pages.

I've done a suggested edit that I hope might help - though I'd say your answer might be "you really can't"

Comment: I believe your edit is more than sufficient to get the question reopened.

Comment: Well that's vaguely the intention, though as a low reputation user here, I'll leave it to people who are familiar with the site to decide on that :D

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If the questions was closed as lacking clarity or details, it sounds like you disagree that it should have been closed for this reason. I hope it gets reopened.

Comment: Oh I was discussing it with a local moderator and felt OP needed a *little* help - I probably ought to answer the other meta question too but I've been a bit distracted :D