# Should we allow questions about (Google) Recorder?

Tags: discussion, tags, scope, tag-creation

Few days ago [google-recorder](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/google-recorder) was created.

This tag doesn't include a tag wiki. The question's original revision that created doesn't include enough detail to make it clear that the question is about a web application.

The product brief of **[Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.recorder)** present it as an app for certain smartphones from Google, more specifically of the brand Pixel. The owners of these phones can upload recordings to Google data centers. They can see the saved recording in https://recorder.google.com.

[image: (Google) Recorder on the Web - Anonymous]

Users that have not saved a recording can't do anything, besides seing the manage Google account button and the Help button.

[image: (Google) Recorder on the Web - Signed In]

The help button points to https://recorder.google.com/about

Help Article [Record audio on your Pixel phone](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/9516618?hl=en) from Pixel Phone Help.

According to [Nikhil Rastogi
Diamond Product Expert](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/thread/106592123?hl=en&msgid=106611169)
 the Web UI doesn't allow to download recordings.

On the early days of Web Applications one of the parameters were to focus on web applications having millions of users.

Do you think that allowing questions about (Google) Recorder will attract *power users of web applications* to this community? If so, please post an insteresting, challenging question and add the link below.

**Related**

- [What kind of questions can I ask here? The detailed version](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/894/88163)
- [The Web Application Nursery](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3803/88163)

**Reference**

- [The On-Device Machine Learning Behind Recorder](https://ai.googleblog.com/2019/12/the-on-device-machine-learning-behind.html)

Answer (score 1):

> Should we allow questions about (Google) Recorder?

Yes, assuming you're asking about https://recorder.google.com. There are no requirements that only websites available for free to anyone are on-topic.

> On the early days of Web Applications one of the parameters were to focus on web applications having millions of users.

I don't believe that is correct (where did you read that?), but anyway that didn't make questions about smaller websites off-topic, e.g. [Browse people by location on Dailymile](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/105/browse-people-by-location-on-dailymile)

Comment: The linked question is one of the [meta-tag:broken-windows] that was still open. Thanks for bringing it to our attention.

Comment: Regarding focus on web applications having millions on users that is my conclusion of the review that I have recently did. You could do your own review of the discussions from early days of this site. To help you and and others that might be interested on doing this I have tagged several of them with [meta-tag:private-beta] , [meta-tag:public-beta] but you also could use the search operators. You could find the dates moderator tools and in the Area 51 proposal.

Comment: @Rubén Thanks, I went through the questions tagged with [private-beta](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/private-beta) , [public-beta](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/public-beta), I didn't read any mention of a focus on web applications having millions on users.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have any concerns about allowing questions about [recorder.google.com](https://recorder.google.com) if they are a good fit for the site.

Given the limited functionality and purpose of the web app, I'm not sure what a good question would even look like but I'm open to the possibility.

As noted in the question, [recorder.google.com](https://recorder.google.com) is an extremely limited web app that provides access to recordings backed up in a Google account from the Recorder Android app on a Pixel phone (see "Recorder settings > Back up & sync" in the Recorder app).

The Recorder app is a competitive differentiator for Google Pixel phones and is unavailable on other Android phones.

While the web app provides some limited tools for recordings backed-up from the Recorder app, it provides nothing if you don't have a Pixel, or have a Pixel but have no backed-up recordings.

The [Recorder app support documentation](https://support.google.com/pixelphone/answer/9516618) never refers to the web app as an app or as Recorder Web but always as [recorder.google.com](https://recorder.google.com)

For example:

> Back up and sync automatically saves your recordings to your Google Account at [recorder.google.com](https://recorder.google.com)

or

> To find and manage your recordings in a web browser, go to [recorder.google.com](https://recorder.google.com)

I appreciate that by its nature [recorder.google.com](https://recorder.google.com) is a web app however questions need to be practical and shouldn't be like the following:

> I use a web app that is intended solely to access the recordings backed up from a Pixel-only Android app to my Google account.  It has some very useful features for those backed-up recordings.
>
> It would be great if I could use the web app to upload recordings from other places instead of simply using it as a tool to access the backed-up recordings from the Recorder Pixel-only Android app.

---

@Flimm commented

> I'm also curious for your example question, would you close it as "lacking details or clarity"? If so, why? In my opinion, that leads to a lot of time wasting as the question asker then tries to add details, only to have the question remain closed.

No.  I would not.  My example is sufficiently detailed and clear.  It is not my intention to waste users' time.  This applies to the ones who might try to answer insufficiently detailed questions, and also, to your point, it applies to users with clear questions that are not a good fit.

I would be likely to use a custom close reason similar to:

> I am voting to close this question because it is at odds with the app's sole purpose which is to provide access to files backed up from the Android Recorder app to your Google account.

Comment: Web Apps is meant for power users. Power users often use web apps for purposes that aren't documented. Are you saying Stack Exchange Web Apps should not allow questions from power users who want to do power user things? If so, how does that justify closing the question as "lacking clarity or details"?

Comment: I'm not saying any of those things.  My answer to the question is basicaly:  "I'm okay with the  tag and the suitability of a particular question should be based on the question as is the case for other web apps we have tags for"

Comment: I think your example question is actually a suitable question (with better phrasing), but I think arguing about it in this comment thread wouldn't be helpful. So I've now deleted some of my old comments here.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying your answer. I'll choose to leave the discussion there, to avoid going off-topic.