# What do we want to show as our target audience?

Tags: discussion, design

Since the discussion about the [intended audience](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5012/) started, a network-wide moderation strike, a moderator election, and a discussion about a site policy. This post is a follow-up intended to reactivate the discussion considering the new context. At the bottom, a list of the answers with the proposed text to update the Web Applications SE audience is included for your convenience.

After a reasonable discussion time of at least two weeks, this [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) might be turned into [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) to ask the CM Team their support to update the Web Applications SE displayed audience to match what the community wants to communicate about it to new users. The goals are

1. To have a clear signal for the Community Management team about the opinion of the active users about updating the displayed audience.
2. To have a proposal that meets the requirements that this text might have.

As of November 6, 2023, take the text below each site name on "MORE STACK EXCHANGE COMMUNITIES" as a reference for the text proposals. Once the CM Team review the proposed text they will provide the corresponding feedback.

Depending on how the discussion evolves, this question might be edited to add the proposed text or the answer might be accepted. Whatever works best and is technically possible at the appropriate time.

---

The Web Applications SE current target audience displayed on the platform is

> power users of web applications

In the site header hero, the More Community Stack Exchange list, the Stack Exchange sites list, among other places

##### Site header hero

> Web Applications Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for **power users of web applications**. It only takes a minute to sign up.

[image]

##### More Community Stack Exchange List

> For **power users of web applications**

| Stack Exchange dropdown menu | Filtered List |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

## Summary of answers to the previous discussion

Items are sorted as shown in the question with the filter Highest Score first.

| Reference | Score | Remarks | Proposed Text when available |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [Franck's answer](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5013/88163) | 2 | Edited on Apr 22 at 22:38 | > Anyone who use public websites (which include websites only accessible via payment or some other conditions such as [owning](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4981/18147) a Pixel 6). |
| [Rubén's answer](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5037/88163) | 2 | Edited on May 19 at 23:16 | > Anybody able to post using English and following the community norms. |
| [galacticninja's answer](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5021/88163) | 2 | No text proposed as of November 6, 2023 |  |

---

Note:

There is another related discussion that is also on "stand-by" for the same reasons [A better name for this community, part 1](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5035/88163) . As explained in that discussion, it was planned to be split into parts to end with an integral feature request to change the site name. As explained in this post, there have been several events between the date those posts were created and this week. The contributions will be added to the summary section above later today or this week. H/T to [galacticninja](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users/7584/galacticninja) for bringing the omission of mentioning this post to our attention.

Update: I added the section "Related", to include another related post. That question is a follow-up to the question mentioned in the above note. It consists of an answer from Flimm. It's not proposing a text related to the audience, so it will not be added to the above summary table.

## Related

- [Web Applications "elevator pitch" (site description ) in Tour](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5042/88163)

Comment: I believe the community, myself included, has already provided suggestions for these back in May 2023: [A better name for this community, part 1](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5035/7584), since that already has sufficient votes for a community consensus, I think you should mark that one as [[meta-tag:status-review]].

Answer (score 3):

I believe the community, myself included, has already provided suggestions for these back in May 2023: [A better name for this community, part 1](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5035/7584). I will reiterate what I've mentioned there:

#### Just change "power users" to "users".

##### E.g., "Web Applications Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for users of web applications."

This is in accordance with the top-voted answers in the meta posts: [Who do outsiders think Web Applications is for, developers/power-users or Joe-user?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/732/7584) and [As of today, May 2023, who do we understand that is our intended audience and what is the first that we tell them about how to participate?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5012/7584)

Comment: Thanks. I will add the referred [question](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5035/) and its answers to the summary a bit later today or during this week. The goal is to make a [meta-tag:feature-request] easy to follow by the CM Team, considering the context after the research discussion policy, which was resolved a few days ago. Before adding [meta-tag:status-review], as it was mentioned, there should be some way to clearly state what exactly is being asked with the support of the active users.