# What shall I add in this question on Slack to have it reopened?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, closed-questions

The question [How can I view the channels that I have been added to recently on Slack?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/169569/18147) was closed because it doesn't show research. It is now deleted due to Roomba. What should I say in the question to show my research?

Question title:

> How can I view the channels that I have been added to recently on Slack?

Question details:

> I wonder the following: How can I view the channels that I have been added to recently on Slack? I Googled and didn't find the answer.

Question screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QijCs.png

A moderator commented:

> Please show what you have tried, share what you found here and in the official resources for Slack end users and why it didn't meet your needs.

I searched the question on Google, and looked at https://slack.com/help, but I didn't see any answer. So what should I say in the question to show my research? My search queries? URLs I looked at? etc.

---

Note: I had asked this question on [How are we supposed to show one's research when posting a question?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4918/18147) but the conversion drifted toward whether showing research is compulsory and I eventually didn't get any answer on how to show research. So I am re-asking here, specifically about what I need to add to reopen the question [How can I view the channels that I have been added to recently on Slack?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/169569/18147) and ignoring everything else.

Comment: Related [Where can I ask general questions about a multi-platform app?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/373040/289691). It mentions Slack as an example.

Comment: @Rubén thanks. From your link "Regarding questions about Slack, my suggestion is that before asking a question you search throughly [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com) 
 and [https://slack.com/help](https://slack.com/help). In your question share what you found and why it didn't meet your needs.". If I found nothing, what shall I say? Is https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/170191/18147 ok?

Comment: Relevant meta discussion started by a community manager about whether we should mandate research on questions: [Does Web Apps Stack Exchange Require Research?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5120/7584)

Answer (score 3):

Your question does not lack clarity or details, and it should not have been closed as lacking clarity or details.

Answer (score -3):

I have saw the [last revision](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/revisions/169569/3) to the question in focus. You have added

> Research: I searched the question on Google, and looked at [slack.com/help](https://slack.com/help), but I didn't see any answer.

With due respect and in the most kind and friendly way that I'm able to write this answer I think that it should be said that you are not taking this seriously or you might need some kind of help that I can't provide. I'm truly sorry for that.

Assuming that you need some kind of help that I can't provide rather than the other option, let say that there have being several feature requests and initiatives to help people needing help write questions that meet the quality standards. There are several posts about this in Meta Stack Exchange I have listed several of them, specially related about mentoring in [Where can I ask general questions about a multi-platform app?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/373040/289691). In it the OP mentioned Slack as an example of cross-platform app.

It's worthy to mention that I have created here [Guides to ask a question about a web application](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4946/88163) but it still requires some work, and as in our previous interactions we were not able to communicate about how to improve your questions, I found my self being naive thinking that you will receive it well. Anyway, I'm open to surprises. I hope to have a nice one soon, like seeing a new question from you in *[Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/)* that meet the [quality standards](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/quality-standards-error).

Comment: Thanks. Let's focus on the question [How can I view the channels that I have been added to recently on Slack?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/169569/18147). How shall I show my research?

Comment: Really? It looks that you didn't understand my answer. I will ask someone else to come and help to translate it to you.

Comment: Your link in [Where can I ask general questions about a multi-platform app?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/373040/289691). says  "Any background research you've tried but wasn't enough to solve your problem.". Your second link https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4947/18147 says "Questions requiring an answer like this should be clear that a reasonable search-research was done to try to solve the problem by yourself before asking the question or to get the question reopened.".  Noted.

Comment: In my [question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/169569/18147), I wrote " I searched the question on Google, and looked at slack.com/help, but I didn't see any answer.". What shall I add to it? The list of queries I tried? The URLs I visited? etc. Let's be concrete.

Comment: This response is really disappointing coming from a moderator. Can the other moderators please chime in?

Comment: i'm having a very hard time understanding what exactly it is this answer is saying. It's almost as if you're saying you didn't see a way you could provide assistance to the user asking the question, and as such felt it should be closed...